# Og:image changed: How to let Facebook refresh link on wall?

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-wall

I posted a couple of my website's links on my facebook page, 
however the image url (og:image) for each of these pages has changed, 
so the link posts on my wall still try to show the image from the old url (which doesn't exist anymore).

How can I make facebook recrawl these links, so that the correct image is shown?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, if you input your url in the debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) it will re-crawl your web. It actually shows you the current result of crawl but I had have to wait several days and even weeks to see the results in my wall.

Comment: weeks!?!? o.O
its should be notified in the documentation